# iOS - UISearchController inside UITableView inside UIAlertController - Searchbar in wrong place when user starts to type

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uialertcontroller, uisearchcontroller

I have a alertcontroller which has a tableview inside it and the table view has a searchcontroller as it's header view.

[image: It looks perfect like this]

This is how it looks. However when I start typing it becomes like:

[image]

I couldn't understand why this happens. Here is my code:

```
resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
resultSearchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Konu Ara"
alertTableView?.tableHeaderView = resultSearchController.searchBar
```

I have updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) method from UISearchResultsUpdating delegate, when this function works the search bar is in the wrong place like in the second picture.

If I delete the line:

```
resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
```

It works perfectly however i lose search functionality because updateSearchResultsForSearchController function is not called. What I am doing wrong?

This is how i create alertcontroller:

```
    let controller = UIViewController()
    var rect:CGRect?
    if (subjects!.count < 4) {
        rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 272, 100)
        controller.preferredContentSize = rect!.size

    }
    else if (subjects!.count < 6){
        rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 272, 150);
        controller.preferredContentSize = rect!.size
    }
    else if (subjects!.count < 8){
        rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 272, 200);
        controller.preferredContentSize = rect!.size

    }
    else{
        rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 272, 250);
        controller.preferredContentSize = rect!.size
    }
    alertTableView  = UITableView(frame: rect!)
    alertTableView!.delegate = self
    alertTableView!.dataSource = self
    alertTableView!.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
    alertTableView!.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "SubjectCell", bundle: nil)
    alertTableView!.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SubjectCell")

    //alertTableView?.tag = kAlert
    controller.view.addSubview(alertTableView!)
    controller.view.bringSubviewToFront(alertTableView!)
    controller.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
    alertTableView?.userInteractionEnabled = true
    alertTableView?.allowsSelection = true
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    alertController.setValue(controller, forKey: "contentViewController")
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    alertTableView?.tableHeaderView = resultSearchController.searchBar

    presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Can you show us how you've created UIAlertController and set the table view as the content of it?

Comment: You can see my edit @ozgur

Comment: can you show us what you have written in delegate method